# Parse JSON Objects with unique strings as parents using JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Let's say I have this example JSON:

```
"Test": {
        "KIf42N7OJIke57Dj6dkh": {
            "name": "test 1"
        },
        "xsQMe4WWMu19qdULspve": {
            "name": "test 2"
        }
}
```

I want to parse this into an Array of a custom class I have, which will be exampled below:

```
class Class1 {

    public string Name { get; set; }

    Class1(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }

}
```

How can I parse this using Json.NET's `JObject.Parse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal with [JPath](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) query like this :

```
var myArray = JObject
    .Parse(json)
    .SelectTokens("$.Test..name")
    .Values<string>()
    .Select(s => new Class1(s))
    .ToArray();
```

But probably not the best way to do it.

I personnaly prefere to create classes to represent the json structure and then apply transformations.

```
void Main()
{
    var json = @"{""Test"": {
        ""KIf42N7OJIke57Dj6dkh"": {
            ""name"": ""test 1""
            },
            ""xsQMe4WWMu19qdULspve"": {
            ""name"": ""test 2""
            }
    }
    }";

    var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
    var array = root.Test.Select(i => i.Value).ToArray();
    array.Dump();
}

public class Root
{
    public Dictionary<string, Class1> Test { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Class1(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, your Json is missing starting/closing braces. The Json needs to have wrapping braces around the Test value.

```
{
    'Test': 
    {
            'KIf42N7OJIke57Dj6dkh': {'name': 'test 1'},
            'xsQMe4WWMu19qdULspve': {'name': 'test 2'}
    }
}
```

If you are missing it in the original Json, you could wrap the current input Json as following.

```
var correctedJson = $"{{{inputJsonString}}}";
```

If you want to parse the Json Objects to Array of `Class1` **without** creating additional **concrete data structures** and using **JPath Queries**, you could use `Anonymous Types` for the purpose using the [DeserializeAnonymousType](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm) Method proved by Json.Net. For example,

```
var sampleObject = new {Test = new Dictionary<string,Class1>()};
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(correctedJson,sampleObject);
var result = data.Test.Select(x=>x.Value).ToArray();
```

You could also achieve it using JPath Query or creating Concrete Data Structures as @Kalten as described in his answer.